# Perl: Is a single grep operation costs same as single for loop?

Tags: perl, for-loop, grep

Say I have a below existing code.

```
my $names = &loadNames();   # No duplicate names
my $u1;
my $u2;
for (my $i = 0 ; $i < @$names; $i++) {
    if($$names[$i] eq $input_one){
        $u1 = loadUserFromOneSource($input_one);
    }

    if($$names[$i] eq $input_two){
        $u2 = loadUserFromSecondSource($input_two);
    }
}
```

Now if I refactored the above code like below

```
my $names = &loadNames();   #Returns array reference
my $u1 = grep $_ eq $input_one, @$names;
my $u2 = grep $_ eq $input_two, @$names;

$u1 = loadUserFromOneSource($u1) if $u1;
$u2 = loadUserFromSecondSource($u2) if $u2;
```

Did I really improve anything? Or I made it even worse because I am running two greps on same list.

Clarification:
The sole purpose of asking the question is to understand the performance trade offs between grep and loop. In both cases I'm extracting out two names. But in first example in a single iteration. And second example it's done in two greps. Did I doubled the cost in second approach? Or grep is efficient enough to win over the single iteration? I will try benchmarking when I will back in work.

Comment: are you having a performance problem?  if not, don't try to improve anything.  as others have noticed, your changes unintentionally changed the functionality.

Comment: `grep` in scalar context is the count of matched items, I think you want `my ($u1) = grep ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, inbuilts like grep will be faster than manual loops.

However in your particular case there are a couple of gotchas:

1. The two code examples don't do the same thing. In the first case, the functions may be called multiple times, if the condition is matched more than once. In the second example the functions can be called at most once.
2. Using an expression like /$foo/ inside a loop or grep, map, etc will result in the regex being compiled each time.
3. Since you did not a anchor the regex, partial matches may also occur.

I would use grep but change the condition to

```
my $u1 = grep $_ eq $input_one, @$names;
```

Comment: Tried to made my question more specific

Answer (score 2):

For one, you're no longer testing for equality in your new code, but for regex inclusion.  That could've introduced a bug.

Another solution is just to translate the arrays to a hash so that you can test if a name exists.  I.e. [perldoc How can I tell whether a certain element is contained in a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-tell-whether-a-certain-element-is-contained-in-a-list-or-array%3f)

```
my $names = loadNames();   #Returns array reference

my %hasName = map {$_ => 1} @$names;

my $u1 = $hasName{$input_one} ? loadUserFromOneSource($input_one) : '';
my $u2 = $hasName{$input_two} ? loadUserFromSecondSource($input_two) : '';
```

Comment: This should be `$u1 = loadUserFromOneSource($input_one) if $hasName{$input_one}` to agree with the OP's first sample. Of course you also need `my ($u1, $u2)` first.

Comment: Or, put undef instead of empty string. Also the cost of constructing the hash is probably not worthwhile if there is only two items to look up. Definitely a better solution if the lookup is needed many times.

Comment: More importantly `$u1` and `$u2` won't contain usernames, they'll contain a count of the number of matches. grep returns a list of matches, or in scalar context (here) the number of matches.#

Comment: Tried to made my question more specific